# Read image files from non-default directory in PrestaShop 1.6

Tags: image, filesystems, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Hello Stack Overflow community, I have installed PrestaShop 1.6.0.14 in a Xampp server a few weeks ago for the company I work for. They have a web application that handles all the image files from their websites, for example, when a user opens an image with right click->open image in different tab or similar, the url shown is something like:

```
http://www.example.net/FileViewer/File.aspx?Type=3&File=WebsiteFileDirectory/img/logo.jpg&Width=138&Height=50
```

As you can see, after the `&File=` part comes a directory structure and some parameters to handle the image at the end. This directory (WebsiteFileDirectory) is located in `C:/StorageFiles/Volume1/`, where the web app for image handling looks for file sources.

My PrestaShop `/img/` folder needs to be in that location with a directory structure similar to `C:/StorageFolder/Volume1/PrestashopFileDirectory/img`. So far, I've moved `/img/` to that location and managed to make Prestashop **write** into the new location by editing the constant values `_PS_IMG_`, `_PS_IMG_DIR_` and `_PS_CORE_IMG_DIR_` in `config/defines.inc.php` and `config/defines_uri.inc.php`

But after that I've hit a brick wall when trying to make PrestaShop **read** from that location, I've even tried editing the `LinkCore::getImageLink()` method by hardcoding a uri_path value pointing to the directory mentioned before, with no results whatsoever, PS will try to read from the default location (something like `myshop/16-small_default/image_filename.jpg`)

How can I make PrestaShop read from that location? Is there even a way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

P.S.: Just to make sure I get a straight forward answer I want to let you know that by now I figured how the image file system in PS 1.6 works, if the image id is 25, PS will store the file in `img/p/2/5/` for a product image, I have no problem with anything related to that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out that getImageLink must be fed a URL (from the image handling webapp I mentioned before), not a filesystem path. So, the `uri_path` variable in this method would look like:

```
$uri_path = 'http://www.example.net/FileViewer/File.aspx?Type=3&File='.$my_img_directory.'&Width=138&Height=50';
```

The methods I have figured so far that need similar tweaking are getMediaLink and getCatImageLink, from the same Link class in the `classes/Link.php` file.